# An idiom or a saying like "give a dog a bone" or "throw someone a crumb"

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, popular-refrains

This expression is often used to describe situations where someone is given a small reward or token gesture to keep them content, while the larger, more significant prize or benefit is kept hidden or withheld. It can also be used more broadly to refer to situations where someone is placated with a small gesture or concession, but the underlying issues or problems remain unresolved.

Comment: What's wrong with the ones you mention? In what kind of context would you like to use it? Please take a look at the tag I added.

Comment: Do "give alms" or "do charity" match what you are looking for ?

Comment: Those *are* idioms. Are you looking for more like that? Even if there are more, the ones you have already identified are probably the best of them.

Comment: There isn't technically a question here. I assume you want an alternative, but it would be good to know more details - if you click on "idiom-requests" and "learn more..." it'll help (sorry that's kind of hidden away).

Comment: As a kid I only heard "give a dog a bone" following "Knick-knack paddy whack".  I've never heard it/read it in adult interchange.

Answer (score 1):

I think the term sop can be helpful in the context you are referring to:

***[sop](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sop)***
noun [ C usually singular ]   disapproving

> something of little importance or value that is offered to stop complaints or unhappiness:
>
> - Critics see the increase in defence spending as a sop to the armed forces rather than an improvement of national security.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

The phrase is "throw (someone) a bone". From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/throw%20a%20bone)

> to offer (someone) something that is not very important or valuable especially to stop complaints or protests
> *The boss would not let his workers out early for the holiday but threw them a bone by buying lunch.*